# How do i set content of a tinyMCE using Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, tinymce, nightwatch.js

I am testing a webapp with nightwatchjs. I need to be able to set the content of a tinyMCE container.  I have tried the simple .setContent for a tinyMCE object but it throws a reference error saying tinyMCE is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use the execute() command to get to the tinyMCE frame and just set the innerHTML of the tinyMCE to what i wanted

```
.execute('var x = document.getElementById("Body1_ifr");  var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument); if (y.document)y = y.document;  y.body.innerHTML = "Article body";')
```

Comment: I came across this same problem, thanks for coming back and posting your solution. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problems using the native TinyMCE API with execute:

```
.execute(function(){
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>Some text</p>')
})
```

or for something more generic, say a page object command:

```
commands: [{
    setBody: function(bodytext){
        return this.api.execute(function(text){
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>'+text+'</p>')
        }, [bodytext])
    }
}]
```